# PyCharm interpreting backward slashes wrong when checking regex expressions

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

The expression is:

```
re.search("(%s)\\(%d)([0-9]+)".format(newspaper, year2))
```

where `newspaper` is a string and `year2` is an integer.

Instead of interpreting `\\` as an escape to the `\` character, PyCharm interprets this as escaping `(` and warns that I have an unmatched closing parenthesis in `(%d)`. It also highlights the opening parenthesis in orange as well. When I replaced this with `\\\`, there is no warning but I'm not able to find my matches with this regex.

Is this how `\` supposed to be escaped or am I missing another character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to: https://regex101.com/

You are correct, `\\` should be escaping the `\`

Try adding an `r` before your regex string and compile it, example:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(%s)\\(%d)([0-9]+)".format(newspaper, year2))
found = re.search(regex, stringy_thing)
```

You can then use the `group` method to probe the returned `found` item(s); regex101 will also show you the *capture groups* in the upper right pane.

Comment: found my matches through r!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it a raw string.

`\\` is interpreted as a single escaped slash in the string, which would escape the `(`, so PyCharm is correctly reporting it as an error.

So, do one of:

```
r"(%s)\\(%d)([0-9]+)"
# or
"(%s)\\\\(%d)([0-9]+)"
```

Also, you probably meant:

```
r"({})\\({})([0-9]+)".format(newspaper, year2)
# or
r"(%s)\\(%d)([0-9]+)" % (newspaper, year2)
```